# Remove negation token and return negated sentence in Spacy

Tags: python, spacy

I want to use dependency parser of spaCy to determine the scope of negation within my docs. See [here](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy?text=RT%20%40trader%20%24AAPL%202012%20is%20ooopen%20to%20Talk%20about%20patents%20with%20GOOG%20definitely%20not%20the%20treatment%20Samsung%20got%20heh%20http%3A%2F%2Ft.co%2FbFPm3CJ3&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=1&cph=1)  the dependency visualizer applied to the following string:

```
RT @trader $AAPL 2012 is ooopen to Talk about patents with GOOG definitely not the treatment Samsung got heh someURL
```

I am able to detect negation cues with

```
 negation_tokens = [tok for tok in doc if tok.dep_ == 'neg']
```

As a result I see that *not* is the negation modifier of *got* in my string. Now I want to define the scope of the negation with the following:

```
negation_head_tokens = [token.head for token in negation_tokens]   
for token in negation_head_tokens:
    end = token.i
    start = token.head.i + 1
    negated_tokens = doc[start:end]
    print(negated_tokens)
```

This gives the following output:

```
 ooopen to Talk about patents with GOOG definitely not the treatment Samsung
```

Now I have defined the scope, I want to add *"not"* to certain words conditional on their POS-tag

```
list = ['ADJ', 'ADV', 'AUX', 'VERB']
for token in negated_tokens:
    for i in list:
        if token.pos_ == i:
            print('not'+token.text)
```

This gives the following:

```
 notooopen, notTalk, notdefinitely, notnot
```

I want to exclude *notnot* from my output and return

```
RT @trader $AAPL 2012 is notooopen to notTalk about patents with GOOG notdefinitely the treatment Samsung got heh someurl
```

How can I achieve this? And do you see improvements in my script from a speed-perspective?

**Full script:**

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(u'RT @trader $AAPL 2012 is ooopen to Talk about patents with GOOG definitely not the treatment Samsung got heh someURL)
list = ['ADJ', 'ADV', 'AUX', 'VERB']

negation_tokens = [tok for tok in doc if tok.dep_ == 'neg']
negation_head_tokens = [token.head for token in negation_tokens]

for token in negation_head_tokens:
   end = token.i
   start = token.head.i + 1
   negated_tokens = doc[start:end]
   for token in negated_tokens:
      for i in list:
         if token.pos_ == i:
            print('not'+token.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's bad form to override Python built-ins like `list` - I renamed it `pos_list`.
2. Since "not" is just a regular adverb, it seems the simplest way to avoid it would be with an explicit blacklist. Maybe there is a more "linguistic" way to do it.
3. I slightly sped up your inner loop.

Code:

```
doc = nlp(u'RT @trader $AAPL 2012 is ooopen to Talk about patents with GOOG definitely not the treatment Samsung got heh someURL')

pos_list = ['ADJ', 'ADV', 'AUX', 'VERB']
negation_tokens = [tok for tok in doc if tok.dep_ == 'neg']
blacklist = [token.text for token in negation_tokens]
negation_head_tokens = [token.head for token in negation_tokens]
new_doc = []

for token in negation_head_tokens:
    end = token.i
    start = token.head.i + 1
    left, right = doc[:start], doc[:end] 
    negated_tokens = doc[start:end]
for token in doc:
    if token in negated_tokens:
        if token.pos_ in pos_list and token.text not in blacklist:

        # or you can leave out the blacklist and put it here directly
        # if token.pos_ in pos_list and token.text not in [token.text for token in negation_tokens]:
            new_doc.append('not'+token.text)
            continue
        else:
            pass
    new_doc.append(token.text)
print(' '.join(new_doc))

> RT @trader $ AAPL 2012 is notooopen to notTalk about patents with GOOG notdefinitely not the treatment Samsung got heh someURL
```

Comment: Thank you Josh for your help! We can use `negation_token` instead of the blacklist, right? More importantly, how can I make sure that the script returns the full sentence `RT @trader $AAPL 2012 is notooopen to notTalk about patents with GOOG notdefinitely the treatment Samsung got heh someurl` and not only the negated-part? Appreciate the help!!

Comment: Can you adjust the script a little for completeness? The `blacklist` should be after `negation_tokens`. There is no direct way to compare _token.text_ with  `negation_tokens`? Only with the indirect route including `blacklist`?

Comment: You are right, those lines should be reversed. I'm not by my computer. As for your second point, I don't think so, since the tokens are not strings.

Comment: Hey - I tweaked it a bit, suggesting a way of omitting the blacklist, although it's pretty similar